# Exporting Access table data to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table in Access 2007 with 11,000 rows and about 20 columns. I want to create a form button that exports the table to an Excel sheet.  The code need to be VBA.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

From access you can also use the [TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214134.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example.

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
                                acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
                                "myQuery", _
                                "C:\myDir\myFile.xls", _
                                True
```

You probably need to make sure that your destination is clear of the output filer (myFile.xls).